# using jdbc api to rollback transcation fail

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

when I using jdbc api to rollback sql, it doesnot work. i wonder where is this the problem?
here is the codes:

```
connection.setAutocommit(false);
statement.execute("create table xxx");
connection.rollback();
```

table xxx should be rollbacked.

Answer (score 1):

You can't rollback the creation of a table. All [DDL operation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html) can't be rollbacked

You can check the doc [statements that can not be rollbacked](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cannot-roll-back.html)